# Training custom dataset for Tesseract and difference between versions

Tags: machine-learning, classification, ocr, tesseract, training-data

I am trying build and then train on a custom dataset to improve OCR of `tesseract`.
However I am having difficulty in understanding the exact steps or the right approach. Please note that I have very few experience in ML, especially in neural networks.
Before starting with my questions I would like to say that I think LSTM was added starting from Tesseract 4 and that for lower versions was used an Adaptive Classifier by default.

I have looked at the doc here: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdoc but honestly I am confused because I have zero experience and by looking a few tutorials I have noticed so much differences.

My questions are:

1. In creating the dataset for tesseract 4 and above I just need the images, the box files and the ground truth files?
2. For tesseract below 4 I just need the images and the box files without the ground truth files?

The text on the images I am trying to recognize are these:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

If you could also provide a detailed explanation on the exact steps for my case scenario I would much appreciate it.